# How can I handle AJAX requests in gatling?

Tags: ajax, gatling

It's that even possible to handle that kind of request? I can't find a decent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From a network perspective, an Ajax request is just a regular HTTP request, sometimes with some specific HTTP headers such as `X-Requested-With` or [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers.

Gatling sends HTTP requests (or other protocol), so it really doesn't care that a request is an "Ajax" one.

Then, Gatling is not a browser, so it doesn't run your client-side JavaScript and won't automatically trigger Ajax requests for you. You have to include them explicitly in your scenario.

Comment: So I should build my scenario just like I'm used to, but I need to keep an eye on proper headers. I will try it. Thanks!